# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, foreach

I am trying to display data from a database, I do not quite understand all the processes that php follows to get and prepare information. The case is that it seems that I do not load what is in the variable `$filas`

> Error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u571414187/public_html/systems/EazyFive/Controlador/cargar.php on line 20

**Cargar.php**

```
<?php

function cargar(){
    $consultas = new consultas();
    $filas = $consultas->cargarDatos;

    echo "<table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Pass</th>
                <th>Canal</th>
                <th>Puntuacion</th>
                <th>url_img</th>
                <th>url_perfil</th>
                <th>logros</th>
            </tr>";

    foreach ($filas as $fila) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$fila['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila['user']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila['pass']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila['canal']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila['puntuacion']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila['url_img']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila['url_perfil']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila['logros']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

**class.consultas.php**

```
<?php

class consultas{
    public function insertarProducto($arg_user, $arg_pass, $arg_canal, $arg_puntuacion, $arg_urlimg, $arg_urlperfil, $arg_logros){
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql = "insert into EzyFive_users (user, pass, canal, puntuacion, url_img, url_perfil, logros) values (:user, :pass, :canal, :puntuacion, :url_img, :url_perfil, :logros)";
        $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':user', $arg_user);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass', $arg_pass);
        $statement->bindParam(':canal', $arg_canal);
        $statement->bindParam(':puntuacion', $arg_puntuacion);
        $statement->bindParam(':url_img', $arg_urlimg);
        $statement->bindParam(':url_perfil', $arg_urlperfil);
        $statement->bindParam(':logros', $arg_logros);  

        if(!statement){
            return "Error al crear el registro";
        }
        else{
            $statement->execute();
            return "Registro creado correctamente";
        }

    }

    public function cargarDatos(){
        $row = null;
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql = "select * from EzyFive_users";
        $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        while($resultado = $statement->fetch()){
            $rows[] = $result;
        }
        return $rows;
    }


}
?>
```

I have also tried to enter `array` in the foreach, and it did not indicate any error to me, but it did not show any information, everything in white
And now if someone can explain me how to capture in error, perfect.

```
                </tr>";

    foreach ((array) $filas as $fila) {
        echo "<tr>";
```

**Conexion.PHP**

```
<?php

class conexion{
    public function get_conexion(){
        $user = "user";
        $pass = "pass";
        $host = "localhost";
        $db = "db";

        $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;", $user, $pass);
        return $conexion;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is new conexion();

Comment: I would guess the `cargarDatos()` is failing and returning `$row = null;`

Comment: Suggest moving the ` if(!statement){` block to directly after the `prepare`

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Are you including the files or using an autoloader?

Comment: $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) can you try this ? it will get you associated array then you can do furthur what you want upon that :)

Comment: What does this line return? `$filas = $consultas->cargarDatos;`. I guess, you want to call `$filas = $consultas->cargarDatos();`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I do it both ways.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Adding these functions, I get a new error **Notice: Undefined property: consultas::$cargarDatos in /home/u571414187/public_html/systems/EazyFive/Controlador/cargar.php on line 5**

Comment: @akrys  return $rows; **Line 37: return $rows; in the file consultas.php**

Comment: You are not including your CLASS scripts or your AutoLoader is not working

Comment: @RubenStryker I was not asking of what you expect, to be returned. I asked, what does it really return. just make a `var_dump($filas);`, and look if you have an array, which you can use to make a foreach loop

Comment: @akrys Sorry, what returns is null xD

Comment: That's what i thought of. I think you don't have a property named 'cargarDatos'. So try a function call `$filas = $consultas->cargarDatos();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the while loop is not necessary, use fetchAll():

```
public function cargarDatos(){
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql = "select * from EzyFive_users";
        $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }
```

Then:

```
$filas = $consultas->cargarDatos();
foreach ($filas as $fila) {
```

[PHP Doc fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not imagined it. Thanks to the others too